# How to do caching of Authorization access token in web api C#?

Tags: c#, api, azure

I have two project.**Project 1** is Php based web API which include OAuth and custom Authorization logic.Where **Project 2** is C# REST API where each API should be authorized.To achieve this I am exposing Api from project 1 for Authorization, which is working perfect.
By above flow for each request to Project 2 API's I have to authorize by hitting the Authorization API's of Project 1.**Do we have any concept in C# or by using some caching technique so that I can check that each request is already validated or not .If not then I should call Authorization API.?**
Input for Authorization API is "**Bearer token**" which will be sent by client application.

**Constraint**:- I have to maintain two different projects and I have to reuse my auth provider API in another web api project.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use redis or any popular out proc cache mgmt to store your token & can be used by both of project.

https://redis.io/clients

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate auth server, for example:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/

And implement SSO(single-sign-on) functionality, if you needed.

Or you can implement your own authorization server, but strongly recommend you to use existing solutions.

Look into this article: 
http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: Thanks alex! :) But I am looking to avoid to authorise each request by some technique which help me to know that my request is already validated. I mean like some kind of expiration policy in web api.